# Multiplying a pandas data frame by a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

```
TownA = [35, 43, 36, 39, 28, 28, 29, 25, 38, 27, 26, 32, 29, 40, 35, 41, 37, 31, 45, 34]
TownB = [27, 15, 4, 41, 49, 25, 10, 30]
Rural = [8, 14, 12, 15, 30, 32, 21, 20, 34, 7, 11, 24]
tv_viewing = TownA + TownB + Rural

labels = np.array(["TownA", "TownB", "Rural"])
stratum = np.repeat(labels, [len(TownA), len(TownB), len(Rural)], axis=0)
sample = pd.DataFrame()
sample["viewership"] = tv_viewing
sample["stratum"] = stratum
sample.groupby("stratum").mean()
```

The above code generates a data frame that looks like this:

| stratum | Viewership |
| --- | --- |
| Rural | 19.00 |
| TownA | 33.9 |
| TownB | 25.125 |

And my goal is to multiply this data frame with the dictionary below:

```
Population = {"TownA": 155, "TownB": 62, "Rural": 93}
```

To get the desired result of:

| stratum | Viewership |
| --- | --- |
| Rural | 1767 |
| TownA | 5254.5 |
| TownB | 1557.75 |

I am not to picky about the final result, the product can be a new column.

I was able to get a solution with below code:

```
a = sample.groupby("stratum").mean().reset_index()
b = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(N, orient='index').reset_index()
ab = pd.merge(a, b, left_on='stratum', right_on='index')
ab["product"] = ab["viewership"]*ab[0]
```

The code produces this table:

|  | stratum | viewership | index | 0 | product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Rural | 19.000 | Rural | 93 | 1767.00 |
| 1 | TownA | 33.900 | TownA | 155 | 5254.50 |
| 2 | TownB | 25.125 | TownB | 62 | 1557.75 |

I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to solve this without resetting the indexes and using some thing like apply.

I have tried this code:

```
a = sample.groupby("stratum").mean().apply(lambda x: x.viewership * N[x.stratum])
```

Only to to get this error:
'Series' object has no attribute 'viewership'

Comment: You seem to think about the apply as being applied by rows, and for that you'll need to pass `axis=1` to apply, then it's applied over rows. (and reset the index, to get the stratum as a column value in apply in that case)

Answer (score 1):

use the `mul` method with axis = 0 :

```py
out = sample.groupby("stratum").mean()
out.mul(Population, axis = 0 )

         viewership
stratum
Rural       1767.00
TownA       5254.50
TownB       1557.75
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the index to a Series, and then use `.map()` on it:

```py
sample["result"] = sample["viewership"] * sample.index.to_series().map(Population)
print(sample)
```

This outputs:

```py
  stratum  viewership   result
0   Rural      19.000  1767.00
1   TownA      33.900  5254.50
2   TownB      25.125  1557.75
```

Answer (score 0):

After groupby, stratum is the index. We can multiply the viewership with a series with the same index and it will match correctly:

```
(sample.groupby("stratum").mean().viewership *
 pd.Series({"TownA": 155, "TownB": 62, "Rural": 93}))
```

```
Rural    1767.00
TownA    5254.50
TownB    1557.75
dtype: float64
```

Note that `pd.Series(mapping)` makes a new series where the keys are the index and the values the series values.